# How to improve detection accuracy by incorporating shape descriptors?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

Below you can see a set of binary shapes that belong to the same object being detected in a video based on color as main feature representation.
[image: shapes]

Since i'm depending on object color in the detection, there might be other irrelevant object presented in the binary mask image because they simply have similar color distribution as the target object of interest (the object to be detected is red car or green car for example)

I tried to distinguish the object based the area and aspect ratio. However, it didn't work efficiently as there were other detected irrelevant objects which their area and aspect ratio fall with in the boundaries of the object to be detected as shown in the below image.

[image: object with non-object]

In the image above the target object is the top white spot.

**As you can see, the set of masks (see first image) captured from different frames of the video slightly differ from each other and shape some similar properties like rectengularity with in certain range**

Therefore, I tried to use additional features such as Rectengularity and **Hu Moments**, since Hu Moment are Scale, position and rotation invariant for a given shape. I also used another properties like area, ratio in order to make the detection more confined in detecting only the target object

As you know, the first two value change slightly with the slight change of the object. i have calculated the min/max value of the first two Hu-values and used them as a threshold.

I did the same for rectengularity, area and ratio and the thresholds were:

```
Min-Hu0=0.20888468
Max-Hu0=0.25578612
Min-Hu1=0.01675855
Max-Hu1=0.03461491
#-----------------
Min-rect=0.5267567567567567 #min_rectengularity
Max-rect=0.9272727272727272
#-----------------
Min-area=705.5
Max-area=1048.0
#-----------------
Min-ratio=1.2777777777777777 
Max-ratio=3.0588235294117645
```

For calculating the rectengularity i did the following:

```
for cr1 in cnts_red:
 area=cv2.contourArea(cr1)
 x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(cr1)
 rectengularity=area/(w*h)
```

I applied these threshold using simply if statements like:

```
if area>=min_area and area<=max_area and 
           aspect=min_aspect and aspect<=max_aspect:
  if rectengularity>= min_rec and rectengularity<= max_rec:

    if HuM[0]>=min_Hu0 and HuM[0]<=max_Hu0 and HuM[1]>=min_Hu1 and HuM[1] 
      <=max_Hu1: 
          
          target_contor =contour
```

It actually shows a very slight improvement, however still detects shapes that are somehow fall in between all these thresholds (see below image)

[image: slight]

**1-So from programming perspective, is this how to threshold based on these properties????**

**2-Despite the fact that i filtered on the rectengularity for the target object, how could the detected irrelevant object which far a way from rectengular shape fall in between the rectengularity boundaries??**

**3-is there some other properties which do improve the detection results?**

**Note: the minimum rectengularity threshold is low due to the fact that the car drives on the curve (see colored image)**

For tests below are images of the object masks at different timestamp  with and without irrelevant objects and one of the original images

[image: original_1]

[image: original_2]

[image]

[image]

[image: 3]

Comment: If you have rotated rectangles for cars, then in place of using the w*h from the bounding box, get the w*h from the rotated rectangle box from cv2.minAreaRect(). It will also tell you the angle or rotation, if you need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `cv2.boundingRect()`, which finds the axis-aligned bounding rectangle, use
[`cv2.minAreaRect()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9), which finds the smallest bounding rectangle (i.e. it finds a rotated rectangle that fits tightest around your shape).

By using the axis-aligned bounding rectangle, you found very small values for rectangularity in your training data. With the smallest bounding rectangle you should only see large rectangularity values for your rectangular objects, no matter how they are oriented.

Comment: As you know, the minAreaRect() return 4 points From them i calculated the width and height and based on several experiments the new values are (Min_rec 0.891064871, Max_rec 1.46875) for the target object. So i filter the contrours according to these new boundaries?

Comment: @k.jbaili: You have `rectengularity=area/(w*h)`. This doesn't change. Just put in the new `w` and `h` (width and height) values computed from the output of `minAreaRect()`. This output should have a `size` attribute that contains the width and height.

Comment: @k.jbaili: If you are getting rectangularity values larger than 1, then there's a problem. The bounding box should always have an area larger or equal to the object's area, and so the ratio must be equal or smaller than 1.

Comment: I understand that only the denominator of the rectengularity equation must be changed into the output of the cv2.minAreaRect(). This method does not return the w and h directly, it returns 4 points of the smallest rotating bounding rect of the object. So i prepared the new w and h and put them in the denominator. I think i'm getting a value greater than one because perhaps the (area in the numerator) that comes from the method cv2.contourArea() is at certain frames larger than the minimum rotating rectangle, isn't that why ?

Comment: @k.jbaili: I haven't tried this, but according to [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html), the method returns an object that contains center, size and angle values. This is true both in OpenCV 3.4 and 4.4 (latest release). I don't know which version you are using, maybe it's older?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. in your previous comment you were talking about the method cv2.minAreaRect(). In your last comment you tagged the cv2.RotatedRect. are they the same ? or which method do you mean i should use? BTY I'm using 4.2.0

Comment: @k.jbaili: Look at the documentation linked in the answer. `minAreaRect()` returns an object of type `RotatedRect`, whose documentation I linked in the comment.

Comment: You're right. Now i understand it. the new values using the minAreaRecht are min 0.7836353575554804, Max 1.0. Believe it or not the oval irrelevant shape has 0.7988 rectengularity !!!!

Comment: according to your knowledge. is there a built-in method of calculating the compactness of the shape??  i think the car would have low compactness and i can use this property as well, don't i?

Comment: @k.jbaili: You've got `cv.convexHull()` to get the convex hull from the counter, then `cv.contourArea()` to get the area of the convex hull. The solidity is the ratio of the area of the object to the area of the convex hull. Here's Python code: https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html

Comment: is solidity the same as compactness ??

Comment: @k.jbaili: There are many different definitions for “compactness” Solidity is one of them. Which definition did you have in mind?

Comment: @ Cris Luengo. I mean how close a shape to a circle ?  The car would have low value of compactness accordingly

Comment: @k.jbaili: Yes, you can take the ratio of the area to the square of the perimeter, smaller values means less circle-like. But the perimeter is less precise (more noise-sensitive) than the area, so this works better for larger objects. But you can certainly add this in for some additional thresholds. You can also use the aspect ratio of the minAreaRect rectangle: `w/h`.

Comment: So  the equation of compactness would be  compactness= ((perimeter)**2)/4.pi.area?

Comment: @k.jbaili: the constant scaling (4 pi) doesn’t matter if all you do is threshold, so you can leave it out. The scaling just makes the feature reach 1 for a circle. Also, your definition of compactness grows for less compact shapes, if you care about the actual values, do the ratio the other way around. But again, as a feature used only for classification it doesn’t matter. Proper roundness measure: *4 pi area / perimeter^2*. But for classification you can do *area/perimeter^2* or the other way around.

Comment: Unfortunately the compactness also doesn't work. Do you agree that i must level up to machine Learning techniques if i want to more generalize the problem?

Comment: @k.jbaili: You are thresholding on all these different features together,  right? Not just on one? If that still is not enough, you’ll have to go back to your color image and either rethink how you binarize it, or get additional texture features to add to your feature set, or rethink your problem from the ground up. You can think of using time continuity (if there’s a car in one frame, there must be one in the next frame too), movement (cars move, other things don’t), location (cars live only on the tracks), etc. By the way, you are already using machine learning techniques.

Comment: Thanks for your support. the image is binarized using histogram back projection algo. I've tried involving the movement (like background subtraction). However, other irrelevant objects such as a human passing by is also a moving object and thus we come back to the same problem. In fact the best solution to this is to search only in the region where the cars drive (area of interest) by multiplying the image with a predefined binary mask to get the ROI. According to your experience, do you think that is a good way of thinking of the problem?

Comment: @k.jbaili: Yes, the more constraints you add, the fewer false positive detections you'll have. Add them all: it must be a rectangle of a given size and given aspect ratio, and it must be within the track region of the field of view, and it must have this particular color, etc. etc. Each constraint you add, you remove more false positives.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a tutorial or example about using time continuity object tracking? .

Comment: @k.jbaili: It's pretty trivial: "is the detected object in this frame close to the detected object in the previous frame?" Just compare centroids, see how far away they are from each other.

Comment: That would work great for me since I already save the Centroids of the detected car in a dequeue. However, I'm asking how would this help distinguishing the car from other irrelevant objects (e.g me crawling on the floor at the bottom of the image) taking into consideration that i'm processing the whole binary image.

Comment: @k.jbaili: I'm sure you are larger than the cars, and not square. I'm talking about **ading** constraints, not replacing all constraints with this one. You need to use **all** of the constraints we've discussed. Adding a temporal constraint can distinguish a car from a postit note of the same color because the postit note does not move.

Comment: Yes Indeed I consider all what we're disscussed. So i should calculate the distance between two centroids of different frames and if the distance is big, that is my object of interest right?

Comment: @k.jbaili: Possibly, yes. Do your cars have a fixed speed? A max and min speed you want to consider? Stick those into your logic.

Comment: Cars has a fixed speed in a video however this speed is different in another video. BUT, what you suggested regarding the distance between centroids essentially works, since i added a constraint of considering a blob my target blob if the distance between centroids in every 5 frames in not larger than 25. however, when the car is not longer visible and the irrelevant object stays at the very beginning it ignores it (because the difference is very big) but as long as it stays in the FOV of the camera the distance gets small till it is less than 25. I will make a new post for that

Comment: I'm so thankful for your patience and collaboration

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following methodology:

- collect a number of images with true positives and false positives, and label every blob as true/false.
- think of the shape features that you are able to compute (isoperimetric ratio, ratio of perimeter/area of the shape and its convex hull, eccentricity of the ellipse of inertia, deviation from the expected size...).
- try classification with a single feature (check if the value of some feature defines two separate subsets; if it works, choose a threshold in between).
- if a single feature does not suffice, you can use a simple classifier such as nearest-neighbor with a small number of features. You can enter just the true samples and threshold on the distance to the nearest, of enter both true and false samples and assign the type of the nearest.

To make the necessary tests, it is highly recommended to automate the task and write an application that outputs the classification score. In any case, do not expect 100% accuracy.

Comment: this is definitely worth a try. I would appreciate if you could post a link of a tutorial that shows how to do it. My programming experience is beginner:(

Comment: @k.jbaili: sorry, most of these items deserve much longer explanation and I know of no tutorials about them.

Comment: So shortly, you mean i need to write a classifier that classifier and train it on labeled data which are images with false positives and negatives. If so, do you know a labeling tool?

Comment: You will have to label "manually" by enhancing your current application that detects the blobs (for instance show blob numbers and let the user pick the true ones).

Comment: Dauost. With labeling you mean decide to which class this blog belongs and assign the ground truth bounding box like in deep learning OR calculating the shape features for the true positive and false positive blobs Or simply by saying this is true and this is false?

Comment: @k.jbaili: for your problem, ground truth is a true/false label for every blob (somehow numbered for reference). You can compute all features immediately (fill a table of features) or postpone this when needed (returning to the original images).

Comment: Daust. Let's say that i label the data so that 1 is truee positive and 0 is false positive. How i'm i gonna save them for example a csv file?

Comment: Write 1 (true) and 0 (false) to the CSV file. If you process the image again later, make sure that the blobs are found in the same order.

Comment: what i don't really get is how i'm i going to prepare the train data for classification. I mean let's say i have 30 mask images for training and 5 for testing. the traiing images are 640x480 binary images each contains two blobs one is ture positive and the other is false positive and i want to train the classifier based on three features: area, ration and rectengularity. First how i'm i gonna have to prepare the imgaes ?

Comment: @k.jbaili: mh, you already have the processed images, don't you ?

Comment: @ Yves Daoust . Aha you mean i don't have to change the dimensionallity of the processed images don't you?

Comment: @k.jbaili: images are 2D, that's it. I am pretty sure that in your case one or two well chosen features will be enough. Or said differently, using tons of features will not help, on the opposite.

Comment: Daust. Thanks for your patience. As you can notice from my question i have a very limited knowledge when it comes to machine learning and other stuff. So one big last question, Since the data in my case are already processed, I need two main things. the first is to label the data and the second is to write a classificator. and then i train this classificator on the trained data and eventually i test the classificator. WHAT IS THE ESSENCE OF THE CLASSIFICATOR that would classifies blobs in the image if they fall between the defined threshold of rectenglularity for example?

Comment: i just have one question regarding my implementation. As you see from the colored image above,  cars have defined trajectory and relatively similar shape (rectangle), so if i search only in the region of the trajectory i would have for 80% solved the problem of detecting false positives shapes since it's unlikely that someone walks on the railroad;;;;

Comment: and with adding an additional feature like trangularity i could improve the detection against false positives lets say 5%, So total is 85%. Now i ask you from methedology perspective, could this be considered as a fine way of thinking of the problem???

Comment: @k.jbaili: trangularity ? 85% seems a poor score. Some kind of rectangularity (area area of rotated bounding rectangle) might help. The methodology is to assess the usefulness of the features by classification.

Comment: Sorry i meant rectengularity

Comment: Sorry, I meant "area vs. area of rotated bounding rectangle".